# How to replace multiple occurences of a character in a java string using replace and charAt methods

Tags: java

This is my second question here and still a beginner so please bear with me.
I have this code of a very basic hangman type game.I have changed the characters to "-",I am able to get the indices of the input but I am not able to convert back the "-" to the characters entered.
Its an incomplete code.

```
    String input;
   String encrypt =  line.replaceAll("[^ ]","-");
   System.out.println(encrypt);

   for (int j=0;j<10;j++){ //Asks 10 times for user input
      input = inpscanner.nextLine();
      int check = line.indexOf(input);
      while (check>=0){
          //System.out.println(check);
          System.out.println(encrypt.replaceAll("-",input).charAt(check));
          check = line.indexOf(input,check+1);
      }
```

Here is how it looks like:
  You have 10 chances to guess the movie
`------`
o
o
o
L
L
u  //no repeat because u isn't in the movie.While 'o' is 2 times.
I would like to have it like `loo---`(looper).
How can I do like this `"[^ ]","-"` in case of a variable?

Comment: It's not going to happen.  You need to fundamentally re-think your approach.

Comment: I am asked to use only scanner,indexof,replace etc,no other method..

Comment: **Hint:** Maybe you can show the player _______ _WITHOUT_ changing the original movie name string?...

Comment: The problem for me remains..how to show the whole line with the correct charcters entered and the remaining hidden..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "xyzwrdxyrs";
    String input;
    String encrypt =  line.replaceAll("[^ ]","-");
    System.out.println(encrypt);
    System.out.println(line);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int j=0;j<10;j++) { //Asks 10 times for user input
        input = scanner.nextLine();
        //int check = line.indexOf(input);
        int pos = -1;
        int startIndex = 0;
        //loop until you all positions of 'input' in 'line'
        while ((pos = line.indexOf(input,startIndex)) != -1) {
            //System.out.println(check);
            // you need to construct a new string using substring and replacing character at position
            encrypt = encrypt.substring(0, pos) + input + encrypt.substring(pos + 1);
            //check = line.indexOf(input, check + 1);
            startIndex = pos+1;//increment the startIndex,so we will start searching from next character
        }
        System.out.println(encrypt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Anil.It surely did.My aim was to not use substring method and do it somehow with charAt and index of methods but I guess I don't have a choice.